# Websites in IIS don't start after windows server 2019 reboot?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

Recently migrated from Server 2012 R2 to Server 2019. First time noticing this odd behavior, that after system reboot the websites setup in IIS don't start and I have to manually start each individually. Checked all settings but can't figure out what's going on?

Note: The issue isn't worker process, its the actual state of the website. The state is set to stopped, so I have to manually select each website and click on Start in the right-side panel.

Comment: What kind of migration? In-place upgrade or other? Sites should auto start if `serverAutoStart` is set to `true` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/#attributes and its default value is also `true`.

Comment: Not in-place, fresh. Copied data and setup websites manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websites are typically demand-started, i.e. the W3WP worker process starts running when a request for that site comes in.

(Unless you set AlwaysRunning to true in the website properties).

Comment: I'm not talking about the worker process. The issue is actual website goes into Stopped state, so I have to manually select each website and click on Start in the right-side panel.

Comment: Look in your System logs for any indication WAS is stopping your website due to crashes? Otherwise, the answer should be in the \windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config file, most likely due to serverAutoStart="false" on the site(s) in question.